# Architecture of a UI with multiple separate components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, architecture, web-component

#### Problem

I have site A written in React.

I want to render smaller React components into site A whenever a user navigates to a certain page within site A.

Each smaller React component lives within its own repository, as does site A.

#### Question

How can I dynamically load these components into site A when site A is in production?

What kind of workflow can I set up for developing the smaller React components locally *within* site A?

---

I was thinking of using Web Components ([https://medium.com/@*rchaves*/building-microfrontends-part-iii-public-path-problem-1ce823be24c9](https://medium.com/@_rchaves_/building-microfrontends-part-iii-public-path-problem-1ce823be24c9)) but don't want to have the components already deployed somewhere and just load those components from the server. Preferably there would be a solution where I can set up something in my pipeline to point to the repositories where the smaller components exist and package those along with the site A code into one bundle whenever any component is built.

That also brings up the other problem of loading the same dependencies multiple times (like React, React DOM) due to different projects being packaged.

Other ideas are possibly using npm modules, iframes, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want complete isolation between the main app and the smaller components, iframes are the way to go as they can ensure that each component can have its own React versions and dependencies.

If you need to share data / interaction between these components and the main app, then adding it as an npm dependency is one way to go. But this will require uniform framework versions across all components. Or you can try web-components.

Comment: iframes would require the smaller components to be already hosted elsewhere and then reference that URL, correct? Not super familiar with them.

Comment: Yes. They do. If these components can by themselves work independently (like ads or google maps), then they need to be hosted outside to be put in an iframe.

Comment: If these components require some data or need to interact with the main app, then you need to add it as the app's dependency

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue with my own project, and I have found [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to work very well.

Another way that I considered, and might prove useful, is to use a [private npm package](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages) with all your smaller components in it.

Comment: Started looking at submodules and they're very nice. Thanks for the suggestion.